# How to get records from both tables using ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 Tables in Ms Access

1. tbl_Master_Employess
2. tbl_Emp_Salary

I want to show all the employees in the employee table linked with employee salary table 
to link both table the id is coluqEmpID in both table

In the second table, I have a date column. I need a query which should fetch records from both tables using a particular date

I tried the following query:

```
select coluqEID as EmployeeID , colEName as EmployeeName,"" as Type, "" as Amt
from tbl_Master_Employee 
union Select  b.coluqEID as EmployeeID, b.colEName  as EmployeeName, colType as Type, colAmount as Amt 
      from tbl_Emp_Salary a, tbl_Master_Employee b  
      where a.coluqEID = b.coluqEID and a.colDate = #12/09/2013#
```

However, it shows duplicates.

Query4

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName    Type    Amt
1           LAKSHMANAN      
1           LAKSHMANAN      Advance 100
2           PONRAJ      
2           PONRAJ          Advance 200
3           VIJAYAN     
4           THIRUPATHI      
5           VIJAYAKUMAR     
6           GOVINDAN        
7           TAMILMANI       
8           SELVAM      
9           ANAMALAI        
10          KUMARAN
```

How would I rewrite my query to avoid duplicates, or what would be a different way to not show duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you are using union when what you want is a join.  The union is first going to list all employees with the first part:

`select  coluqEID as EmployeeID , colEName as EmployeeName,"" as Type, "" as Amt
from tbl_Master_Employee`

and then adds to that list all employee records where they have a salary with a certain date.

```
Select  b.coluqEID as EmployeeID, b.colEName  as EmployeeName, colType as Type, 
colAmount as Amt 
from tbl_Emp_Salary a, tbl_Master_Employee b  
where a.coluqEID = b.coluqEID and a.colDate = #12/09/2013#
```

Is your goal to get a list of all employees and only display salary information for those who have a certain date?  Some sample data would be useful.  Assuming the data here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1db67/4) this query should create what you want.

```
Select a.coluqEID as EmployeeID, colEName as EmployeeName, 
       b.colType as Type, b.colAmount as Amt
FROM tbl_Master_Employees as a 
LEFT JOIN (select coluqEID, colType, colAmount FROM tbl_EMP_Salary 
           where colDate = '20130912') as b ON a.coluqEID = b.coluqEID;
```

The first step is to create a select that will get you just the salaries that you want by date.  You can then perform a join on this as if you were performing a separate query.  You use a `LEFT JOIN` because you want all of the records from one side, the employees, and only the records that match your criteria from the second side, your salaries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need a join, however as to your question on Unique names.

```
select **DISTINCT** coluqEID as EmployeeID
```

Adding the distinct operator would give only uniquely returned results.